# How to upload and retrieve a video file from wowza server?

Tags: android, wowza

I have to upload a video file which is recording from android mobile camera to wowza server and retrieve the uploaded file from wowza server to android mobile. How can I specify that path using rtmp or http (how to get path)? How can I achieve this? Can anybody help me?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Do you have a link to the APIs that you are using?

Comment: is that possible for connecting wowza server in android for video recording.